# Is there a way to display PDF on Apple tvOS?

Tags: pdf, tvos, apple-tv

I just started exploring Apple's tvOS and am looking if there is a way to display PDFs in a carousel or of that sorts. However, I cannot find a way to achieve that without converting PDF to JPEG images. Can someone guide me if there is a Document object that can read and render PDF on tvOS?

Comment: Not at the moment, as web view, document preview controller, safari view controller are not supported ...

Comment: Ever have any success with this?

Answer (score 2):

I think CGPDFPage and its related API:s are available, https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgpdfpage/